# Close articles sections and update urls in AngularJS 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to do the following in AngularJS 2:

In my App, I have open 3 sections and the URL would be something link this

www.site.com/section-1/section-2/section-3/

each section has a [X] close button, when I press that close button should close the section but also update the URLs, and If I close for eg: "section-2" should kill "section-3" as well. section-1 can not be closed because if the main section (father of all sections)

Will be very grateful if you can help me, Thank you :)

[Click here to see descriptive image of desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNYtL.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Router,RouterLink} from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
    selector: 'menu-header',
    template: `
                <div style="height:20px;width:200px;background-color:red">
                    <div>Title</div>
                    <div><a [routerLink]="['../Empty']">Close By URL</a></div>
                    <div><a (click)="Close()">Close BY JS</a></div>
                <div>
    `,
    directives:[RouterLink]
})
​
export class HeaderComponent{
    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(private _router:Router) {
    }

    Close(){
        alert('going to close');
        this._router.navigate(['../Empty']);
    }
}
```